# Marlin 2.1 reboots before printing model when power recovery is enabled

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, firmware

Ender 3 Pro with Creality 4.2.7 board. Just flashed Marlin 2.1.
Enabled POWER_LOSS_RECOVERY

Problem: The printer will successfully go through auto leveling and the clean/prep line on the left side. When the line finished I see the LCD rebooting. If I disable Power Loss Recovery in the menu it will start the print without any issue. Already tried reflashing but no luck. Any idea how I can print with Power Loss Recovery enabled?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with marlin 2.1.x bugfix. I just downloaded it this morning, installed it on 6 machines.

If power loss is disabled absolutely everything works, but as soon as I enable power loss recovery, it will auto home all, heat up the bed and nozzle, do the purge line on far left of build plate, attempt the very first layer, and then reboots, reheats, and keeps retrying...

Funny thing is that for some reason my printers print so much better with Marlin 2.1, so I really need power loss to work as well.

Comment: Yes, that sounds like the same issue. Right now i'm running Creality's release from their hompage. Not a perfect solution as babystep Z is only 0.1 increments and i need to reverse the filament runout sensor's activated position which isn't possible without the source code. (The source code offereded on their own page didn't work correctly either)